# sed /foo/,/bar/ * matches across file boundary

Tags: regex, sed

I have files *.txt with content

```
blah blah. Management blah
stuff I don't want blah

Management 09/10/15
stuff I do want

Overview
```

When processing a single file with

```
sed -nr '/Management.[0-9]/{:a;n;/Overview/b;p;ba}' 1.txt
```

I get

```
stuff I want
```

When processing multiple files with the same command

```
sed -nr '/Management.[0-9]/{:a;n;/Overview/b;p;ba}' *.txt
```

I get

```
stuff I don't want blah

Management 09/10/15
stuff I do want
```

What gives? I need something like

```
/Management[[:space:]][0-9]
```

But can't sort out how to fit that into SED. 
I think I had this last night, then closed without saving. (however, I hadn't checked that deep into the data and might've missed something. Trying to reconstruct from bash history has led me here).

These text files are converted from PDFs and spaces may be non-breaking.

Comment: What exactly is your question ? Are those all lines in different files ?

Comment: You have a loop with `n` in it.  The state of sed doesn't magically reset at the start of each file.  If you need that, you'll need to arrange for sed to be run separately per file (with a loop, or with `xargs -n 1`, for instance).

Comment: Is this the exact command? `/Management*[0-9]/` Doesn't match `Management` followed by a space, i.e., none of your example lines.

Comment: @TobySpeight Prior to posting, I tried 'for f in *.txt; do  sed -nr '/Management.[0-9]/{:a;n;/Overview/b;p;ba}' $f >> output; done
' which fails on this line ' Management reviews the financials of each of these operating units every month and (line break here)

• Commodities such as gold and copper are key materials in'

Comment: @BenjaminW. Whoops. I'm no regex pro. I used '.' also with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `/Management*[0-9]/` is a shell glob pattern, where `*` means "zero or more of any characters". see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching for more details

You want sed regular expressions, documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions

```
/Management \+[0-9]/
```

That's the word Management, followed by one or more spaces, followed by a digit.

Comment: ' sed -nr '/Management \+[0-9]/{:a;n;/Overview/b;p;ba}' BRK.txt' returns nothing.  'sed -r '/Management \+[0-9]/{:a;n;/Overview/b;p;ba}' BRK.txt' returns the entire file. also failed 'sed -nre /Management[[:space:]]' and '\s\'

Comment: Instead of the fancy loop, try selecting an address range: `sed -nr '/^Management[[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]/,/^Overview/ {/^Overview/d;p;}' *.txt`

Comment: For your command, just remove `-r` -- that option enables "extended regular expressions" which change the meaning of `+` and parentheses and braces so you don't need to escape them.

Comment: If you don't want to see the `Management` line in the output: `sed -n '/^Management \+[0-9]/,/Overview/{//d;p}' file ...` -- the empty regular expression tells sed to re-use the previous one that matched.

Comment: both of those fail, too. File was converted from a PDF; spaces may be non-breaking. Would that create an issue?

Comment: no doubt. Try this: `od -c file.txt` and see what those characters actually are. `[[:space:]]` or `[[:blank:]]` may pick up unicode-y whitespace, depending on your locale

Comment: M   a   n   a   g   e   m   e   n   t 302 240   0   1   /   1

Comment: See if `/Management[[:blank:]]\+[0-9]/` works. Otherwise, a common regex idiom is match some characters that **don't** match a particular pattern: `/Management[^0-9]\+[0-9]/` -- "management" followed by some non-digits followed by a digit. That's now to implement non-greedy matching in a regex engine that does not support the `*?` and `+?` quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the material between a line containing `Management` and at least one digit and the next line containing `Overview`, that's what you ask `sed` to produce:

```
sed -n -e '/Management.*[0-9]/,/Overview/ { /Overview/d; p; }'
```

Given a file `data` containing:

```
blah blah. Management blah
stuff I don't want blah

Management 09/10/15
stuff I do want

Overview
Not wanted
Please ignore
```

The output I get is:

```
$ sed -n -e '/Management.*[0-9]/,/Overview/ { /Overview/d; p; }' data data
Management 09/10/15
stuff I do want

Management 09/10/15
stuff I do want

$
```

Comment: 'sed -n -e '/Management.[0-9]/,/Overview/ { /Overview/d; p; }' data data (note change from .* to .) succeeds on single file, fails on batch processing on line 'Management is also recycling capital (and then some)' and others.

Comment: Please show in the question what you mean.  We can't guess what you don't show clearly as input and desired output.